# Multiple app.post request but I get asertion error nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, request, handler, restify

post request a few but I can not make multiple post request or get request
When I write multiple app.post() or app.get I get error this error : 
Assertion error :(function) is required  How to fix this problem thnks all of you...

APPjs

```
var restify = require('restify');
var config = require('./config');
var app = restify.createServer({name:'REST-api'});

app.use(restify.fullResponse());
app.use(restify.bodyParser());
app.use(restify.queryParser());

app.listen(config.port, function() {
    console.log('server listening on port number', config.port);

});
var routes = require('./routes')(app);
```

Route.JS

```
module.exports.my = function(app) {
    var user = require('./controllers/userController');
    var location=require('./controllers/locationController');
    var ilan=require('./controllers/ilanController');

    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        return res.send("WELCOME TO REST API");
    });


        //User get and create
       app.post('/createUser', user.createUser); //Create Student API

       app.get('/getUser',user.getUser);

          //Ilan get and create

        app.post('/createIlan',ilan.createilan);
        app.get('/getIlan',ilan.getian);

              //Location

         app.get('/getlocation', location.getLocation);

};
```

DB.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var config = require('./config');

mongoose.connect(config.dbPath);
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', function () {
    console.log('error occured from db');
});

db.once('open', function dbOpen() {
    console.log('successfully opened the db');
});

exports.mongoose = mongoose;
```

Comment: i cannot see mongoDb file required and used anywhere this can be the reason

Comment: thnks for your response :) but I had syntax error ,  app.post('/createIlan',ilan.createilan);  I changed with   "ilan.createIlan" my function name was that :)

Comment: @MAD Does this mean your problem is solved?

Comment: yeah its solved

Answer (score 0):

`Assertion error :(function) is required` - this is head of error. You should to read trace bellow this error. Hope this helps.